# back button close the activity instead of going back to main activity

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, appcompatactivity, back-button-control

in AndroidManifest.xml I put this

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

In onCreate() method I put this. I didn't override onOptionsItemSelected.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

The problem is when I press the Back button(on the action bar) The activity get closed instead of going back!  Help me to resolve this. Why I go for this method is I can easily place a back button on the left.

Comment: have you called finish() when you start activity?

Comment: "when I press the Back button". Do you mean the back button on the action bar, or the one on navigation bar? In that case, you have to override onBackPressed method. Let me know

Comment: Please post the code for creating intent for starting activity as well.

Comment: @FonzTech Back button on the action bar

Comment: @Pavya yes !Intent intent =new Intent(Customer_Screen.this,Customer_MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent); finish(); I have done it ! Now I know the problem ! andthx for the anser!

Comment: @Alireza Yha I found the problem ! i put finish() .. Thx!